# If $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've been asked to solve the following problem and I believe that I have gone about it correctly but I would appreciate a second look from someone with more experience.

**Question**: If $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a$?

Since $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, $f+g$ and $f$ are continuous at $a$.

Observe

\begin{align*}(f+g)^{\prime}(a)-f^{\prime}(a)&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(f(x)+g(x))-(f(a)+g(x))}{x-a}-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(f(x)+g(x))-(f(a)+g(x))-(f(x)+f(a))}{x-a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\\
&=g^{\prime}(a).
\end{align*}

Thus, if $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, then $g$ must be differentiable at $a$

I feel that I went about this proof correctly, however the move from two limits to a single limit seems like it might have been done incorrectly.

Comment: What you have done is absolutely correct. You can always change the two limits into one if you know the limits converge.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to use the limit definition. If $p$ and $q$ are differentiable at $a$, then so is $p - q$; the proof of this fact is essentially what you wrote. Here $p = f+ g$ and $q = f$.